# Zurb Foundation 5 not working in IE 10?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, internet-explorer-10

I have been waiting forever to switch to foundation.  Now that we finally getting close to have IE10 (@#$&%^??!!), the main foundation website does not even work in IE10.  It was definitely fine a few months back with foundation 4.  Did I miss something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a rant.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to find out if Zurb Foundation 5 is working with IE10.  When I go to the main website, it works fine in Chrome, but not in IE10.  I haven't done anything special with my IE, everything standard.  Really want to know if Foundation is an option.

Comment: Why all the negatives and request to close?  I'm simply asking if Foundation 5 works in IE10.  It doesn't on my machine, wondering if I missed anything.  Anyone has the answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 10 was set in compatibility mode.  Foundation 5 works fine with IE10 once that's resolved.